# SQL Temp DB , Difference Between Temporary tables & Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hashtable, temp-tables

I would like to know that, Does creating a table in  the **table section** of **TempDB**  differ from creating a Hash table.

Creating a table in Temp DB

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[abc]    Script Date: 2/14/2017 4:04:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[abc](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Creating a Hash Table

```
CREATE TABLE #abcd(
id INT,
name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #abcd VALUES (1,'22')
```

Are these  Table in the temp DB and Hash table same ? 
I mean does this normal table behave like a temporary table since it has been created in the temp DB??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does creating a table in the table section of TempDB differ from creating a Hash table.Are these Table in the temp DB and Hash table same ?

`dbo.temp` in `TempDB` will persist until system reboot.since Tempdb will be recreated from scratch ,after any reboot (using Model database as template)

`#temp` will persist only for that session

There are also some more differences,which apply to #temp like, you can't create

1.triggers
2.Foreign keys

In summary,dbo.temp in TempDB acts just like normal table

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this:

```
USE [tempdb]
```

That's not the way it works. Doing what you are doing in your second query without the above line will automatically use `tempdb`:

```
-- this creates a temp table in tempdb for you
CREATE TABLE #abcd(
id INT,
name varchar(10)
)
```

You don't have to specify that. The first query isn't correct. You shouldn't specifically try to write to `tempdb`, SQL server manages the creation and tidy up of tables in there, so you don't have to.

If you have an open query, then it's good practice to do this when you're done:

```
DROP TABLE #abcd
```

Otherwise the temp table will persist. If it's created in a stored procedure, once it's out of scope, the temp table will be cleaned up for you.

Comment: "If it's created in a stored proc, once it's out of scope, the temp table will be cleaned up on a schedule." - not sure what you're trying to say here. Temp tables created within a stored proc are explicitly documented to be dropped when the stored procedure returns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok, that's a gap in my understanding, good to know.

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) I was referring to (check the first bullet point under Temporary Tables)